# Capture high resolution video/image html5

Tags: html, webcam, getusermedia

I use geUserMedia() to capture image from webcam [Intro](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

Best resolution that I get is **640 X 480**, but I have HD webcam that 
records video with **1280 X 720**,
takes a picture **2592 X 1944**.

How can I capture High Resolution photos?

Here is one sample of code. It doesn't care about canvas size:

```
<video autoplay id="vid" style="display:none;"></video>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1280" height="720" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas><br>
<button onclick="snapshot()">Take Picture</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var video = document.querySelector("#vid");
    var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var localMediaStream = null;

    var onCameraFail = function (e) {
        console.log('Camera did not work.', e);
    };

    function snapshot() {
        if (localMediaStream) {
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    navigator.getUserMedia({video:true}, function (stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        localMediaStream = stream;
    }, onCameraFail);

</script>
```

Comment: You can get full resolution pictures by using the Media Capture API. See the answers here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/36473227/200987

Answer (score 12):

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

=> Setting media constraints (resolution, height, width)

Comment: It's something new (wasn't there before). I'll take a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know WebRTC is currently limited to 640x480 no matter what camera you have. Hopefully this will change soon.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else like me who finds themselves here, there's a useful update at http://webrtchacks.com/video-constraints-2/.

Looking at the original question, note that as far as I understand taking a still photo using WebRTC is actually extracting a still frame from the video feed, so you will always be constrained by the video resolution of the device, even if it is capable of capturing higher resolution stills itself.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below constraints to set a range of resolutions but the snapshot seems to be tied to the video size

```
var constraints = {
      audio: {deviceId: undefined},
      video: {
           deviceId: vid ? {exact: vid} : undefined
         , width: { min: 1280, max: 1560 }
         , height: { min: 720, max: 1440 }
      }
   };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(gotStream).catch(handleError)
```