# Capturing an image in HTML5 at full resolution

Tags: javascript, html, getusermedia, mediastream

It is possible to capture an image in javascript using the MediaStream API.  But in order to do so it is first necessary to instantiate a video object, then paint a frame into a canvas to get an image.  But unfortunately many devices (e.g. phones) don't allow you to capture a video at the full native resolution of the device. For instance, on my phone the maximum image resolution is on the order of 4000x3000 but the maximum video resolution is a mere 1920x1080.  Obviously capturing an image which is only barely 1/6th of the available resolution is unacceptable.

So how can I access the full resolution of the camera on the device?

Comment: You can try http://stackoverflow.com/q/17241707/918910

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't record a full-resolution picture using the MediaStream API, but you *can use the Media Capture API*.

The MediaStream API is able stream data from the camera, but as a video at a video resolution. This is why you can't make photos with a high resolution.

The alternative is to use the [Media Capture API](https://w3c.github.io/html-media-capture/). It simply overrides the `HTMLInput` element by adding a `capture=camera` to the accept parameter. The result is that the native photo app opens to take a picture. This feature is currently (Nov 2017) [only implemented in mobile browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=html-media-capture), so you still need WebRTC as a fallback if you need to support this feature on the desktop.

**Working example**

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById('myFileInput');

function sendPic() {
    var file = myInput.files[0];

    // Send file here either by adding it to a `FormData` object 
    // and sending that via XHR, or by simply passing the file into 
    // the `send` method of an XHR instance.
    
    console.log(file);
}

myInput.addEventListener('change', sendPic, false);
```

```html
<input id="myFileInput" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

I feel like the current situation of the MediaStream API is to access the camera of a desktop and not to actually use it to take photos with.

Comment: For the time being, capture=camera works for me! thanks!

Comment: FYI - this input type='file' will prompt for a filename in a Windows PC browser, but on a mobile device it all show the camera with the camera options (checked on ios ipad and android mobile),